# Can I write tests for invalid lifetimes?

Tags: testing, rust

I'm writing some Rust code that manipulates raw pointers. These raw pointers are then exposed to users through structures that use [ContravariantLifetime](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/kinds/marker/struct.ContravariantLifetime.html) to tie the lifetime of the struct to my object.

I'd like to be able to write tests that validate that the user-facing structures cannot live longer than my object. I have code like the following:

```
fn element_cannot_outlive_parts() {
    let mut z = {
         let p = Package::new();
         p.create() // returns an object that cannot live longer than p
    };
 }
```

This fails to compile, which is exactly what I want. However, I'd like to have some automated check that this behavior is true even after whatever refactoring I do to the code.

My best idea at the moment is to write one-off Rust files with this code and rig up bash scripts to attempt to compile them and look for specific error messages, which all feels pretty hacky.

Comment: Alas, there isn’t native support for tests for failing compilation. rustc itself has infrastructure for achieving this (`src/test/compile-fail` et al.), but it’s custom and not generally available.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: Do you believe there would be interest in the community for supporting this kind of tests? Rust has a really evolved type system allowing to enforce lots of checks, and it seems good to verify that the checks are actually enforced. In the past, with C++, I used Clang's specific tests (`-verify` flag + Clang's specific comments) for this kind of things; it's quite advanced.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: I know that I would like the ability to, when designing a library, have tests verifying that certain code doesn’t compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Rust project has a special set of tests called "compile-fail" tests that do exactly what you want.

The [compiletest crate](https://crates.io/crates/compiletest_rs) is an extraction of this idea that allows other libraries to do the same thing:

```
fn main() {
    let x: (u64, bool) = (true, 42u64);
    //~^ ERROR mismatched types
    //~^^ ERROR mismatched types
}
```

---

One idea that gets halfway there is to use Cargo's "features".

Specify tests with a feature flag:

```
#[test]
#[cfg(feature = "compile_failure")]
fn bogus_test() {}
```

Add this to Cargo.toml:

```
[features]

compile_failure = []
```

And run tests as

```
cargo test --features compile_failure
```

The obvious thing missing from this is the automatic checking of "was it the right failure". If nothing else, this allows me to have tests that are semi-living in my codebase.

Answer (score -4):

You are able to annotate a test that you expect to fail.

```
#[should_fail]
```

As such, you can write a test that attempts to breach the life time it should have, and thus fail, which would actually be a pass.

For an example of a test for 'index out of bounds' see below (pulled from the [Rust guides](http://doc.rust-lang.org/guide-testing.html))

```
#[test]
#[should_fail]
fn test_out_of_bounds_failure() {
    let v: &[int] = [];
    v[0];
}
```

I believe that this example would be a compilation error, so it would stand to reason your compile lifetime violation error would be caught by this too.

Comment: `#[should_fail]` is for runtime failures (now called "panics"), not for compilation errors.

Comment: Perhaps we need to push for a `#[should_fail_compile]` (semi-serious)