# How do I write a test assuring a compilation error?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, rust, integration-testing

I want to prove that my API statically prevents an invalid usage by failing to compile.

There is tooling for assuring that code panics at run-time (`#[should_panic]`), but I couldn't find anything for compilation failure. The doc tests seem most promising, because every snippet is a separate compilation unit, but panic check is all there seems to be.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There isn't currently a way of indicating that a regular test should not compile. And by the look of related issues ([#521](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/521) and [#1994](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/1194#issuecomment-70582397) ) something like `#[compile_fail]` is unlikely to become available any time soon.

However, there are two other ways to write these tests.

#### Doctests

Since [Rust 1.22](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2017/11/22/Rust-1.22.html), you can make *doc tests* which are supposed to fail to compile, by labeling the code snippet with `compile_fail`:

````
/// Foos a bar.
/// 
/// # Example
///
/// ```compile_fail
/// foo(3); // 3 is not a bar
/// ```
fn foo(bar: Bar) {
}
````

#### Compile-test toolkit

The compile-test tools used internally by the Rust project were extracted into the dedicated crate [`compiletest_rs`](https://crates.io/crates/compiletest_rs).

With the boilerplate suggested in the [documentation](https://github.com/laumann/compiletest-rs/blob/master/README.md), one can write compile-fail tests in the `tests/compile-fail` folder:

```rust
fn main() {
   let x: bool = 0;
}
```

See also:

- [Can I write tests for invalid lifetimes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26664770/1233251)

---

These tests should be written with care, nevertheless. Quoting from the announcement of the `compile_fail` feature:

> Please note that these kinds of tests can be more fragile than others, as additions to Rust may cause code to compile when it previously would not.